# MMQGIS - Failure conneting to API (WinError 10061)

Tags: mmqgis

After setting up the the Geocode/Geocode CSV with Google/OpenStreetMap I get the following error:

[image: WinError 10061]

My .csv is set up in UTF-8; QGIS release is 3.14 Madeira.

Any ideas what is causing the abovementioned error?